# Flex 3: refreshing repeater after adding a child

Tags: xml, apache-flex, repeater, appendchild

Within a child, I have an XML element with the following structure:

```
<position>
    <startOffset>*NUMBER*</startOffset>
    <numDays>*NUMBER*</numDays>
    <role>*String*</role>
    <student>*String*</student>
    <conflict>*BOOLEAN*</conflict>
</position>
```

I then use a repeater to list each  out onto the screen.  There's a button I have created that is used to create a position.  So, once the user clicks this button, I call the following function:

```
private function addPosition(index:Number):void
{
    var tempObject:XML = XML("<position><startOffset>0</startOffset><numDays>3</numDays><role>1C</role><student> </student><conflict>false</conflict></position>");             
    projectPositions.appendChild(tempObject);
    projectHeight += 35;
    parentApplication.checkOverlap();           
}
```

The above function creates a new XML object, puts some default values in, and appends it to the list of project positions.  After appending the new information, I made the height of the project larger and then check to make sure the new project height isn't overlapping any other projects... but that information is irrelevant to this post.

My problem is this - once i append a new child to the XML variable, it doesn't appear on the screen.  Is there a "refresh" or "re-render" option i can do to the repeater in order to make the new child show?

*EDIT* - additional information

Here's the variable declaration (information is coming from the parent):

```
[Bindable] public var projectPositions:XML;
```

Here's the repeater (which actually calls another child):

```
<mx:Repeater id="indPositions" dataProvider="{projectPositions.children()}" startingIndex="0">
    <components:block height="38" alpha=".75" 
        id="thisBlock" visible="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
        width="{projectWidth}"
        oneDay="{Number(oneDay)}"
        position="{indPositions.currentItem.role}"
        offSet="{indPositions.currentItem.startOffset}"
        numDays="{indPositions.currentItem.numDays}"
        sName="{indPositions.currentItem.student}"
        isConflict="{indPositions.currentItem.conflict}"
        projectName="{projectTitle}"
        totalSpan="{returnSpan()}"
        projectsHttp="{projectsHttp}"
        allStudents="{allStudents}"
        thisBlockID="{indPositions.currentIndex}"
    />
</mx:Repeater>
```

Then, once the user clicks on the "Add position" button, the following function is called:

```
private function addPosition(index:Number):void
{
    var tempObject:XML = XML("<position><startOffset>0</startOffset><numDays>3</numDays><role>" + possiblePositions[index] + "</role><student> </student><conflict>false</conflict></position>");
    positionsList.addItem(tempObject);
    projectHeight += 35;
    parentApplication.checkOverlap();
}
```

That is what I tried doing first (when i made this post)... then i changed some stuff up after your responses and ended up with this:

Declarations:

```
[Bindable] public var projectPositions:XML;
[Bindable] public var projectXMLList:XMLList = XMLList(projectPositions);
[Bindable] public var projectPositionsXLC:XMLListCollection = XMLListCollection(projectXMLList);
```

Repeater:

```
<mx:Repeater id="indPositions" dataProvider="{projectPositionsXLC}" startingIndex="0">
```

addPosition Function:

```
private function addPosition(index:Number):void
{
    var tempObject:XML = XML("<position><startOffset>0</startOffset><numDays>3</numDays><role>" + possiblePositions[index] + "</role><student> </student><conflict>false</conflict></position>");               
    projectPositionsXLC.addItem(tempObject);
    projectHeight += 35;
    parentApplication.checkOverlap();           
}
```

Once i make the changes, and use the XMLListCollection as the dataprovider in the repeater, the information no longer loads on the screen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure `XMLList` can't be a valid source of data binding handling list changes. To have rid of proper data binding use [`XMLListCollection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html#eventSummary) instead.

Comment: My variable i'm using as the dataprovider is declared like this:[Bindable] public var projectPositions:XML; and in my repeater itself, my dataprovider is defined like this: dataProvider="{projectPositions.children()}"

Comment: Right. It is `XMLList`. Try to use `XMLListCollection` instead. And add new values there.

Comment: I tried converting the XML variable i currently have to an xmllistcollection and then using that, and I end up with the same results... I can see, via alerts, that the item has been added, but it's not displaying to the user.

Comment: Ok, can you add more code (variable declaration, repeater part, adding value part)?

Comment: I've added more code... it's below the "EDIT - additional information" part of the first post

Comment: What do you mean as "the information no longer loads on the screen" ?

Comment: None of the information held within the XML variable is displayed on the screen

Comment: You should initialize all the fields when initialize your XML. Now you do it wrong.

Comment: what fields?  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying

Comment: You have 3 fields `projectPositions`, `projectXMLList` and `projectPositionsXLC` and you're trying to initialize them in process of declaration. Why do you think it should work in any way? There is no any single reason why it will be work.

Comment: Instead of going back to the beginning and making the item an XMLListCollection, i was going to see if i could convert it from an XML to an XMLListCollection just for testing purposes.